# split não retorna arranjo com os elementos da string

Tags: java, string, split

Estou com problemas no uso do método `split`, que não está me retornando o array com os elementos da string.

```
public class Teste{


    public static void main (String[] args){

        String s = "0.101110";

        String[] partes = s.split(".");

        for (int i = 0 ; i < partes.length ; i++){

            System.out.println("Elemento " + (i+1) + ": " + partes[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("tamanho array: " + partes.length);
        System.out.println("string: " + s); 

    }
}
```

Minha saída está sendo:

> tamanho array: 0
>   string: 0.101110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), o parâmetro do método `split` deve ser uma [expressão regular](http://rexegg.com/).

E como em expressões regulares o ponto tem significado especial (significa ["qualquer caractere"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef)), ele deve ser escapado com `\` para que perca este significado especial e seja interpretado como o próprio caractere `.`:

```
String s = "0.101110";
String[] partes = s.split("\\.");

for (int i = 0; i < partes.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Elemento " + (i + 1) + ": " + partes[i]);
}

System.out.println("tamanho array: " + partes.length);
System.out.println("string: " + s);
```

Lembrando que dentro de uma string o caractere `\` [deve ser escrito como `\\`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).
A saída é:

> Elemento 1: 0
>   Elemento 2: 101110
>   tamanho array: 2
>   string: 0.101110

---

Outra alternativa é usar a classe [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), que possui o método [`quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-), que faz o escape do ponto (ou seja, não precisa do `\`, pois o método retorna uma string já devidamente escapada):

```
String[] partes = s.split(Pattern.quote("."));
```

E uma [terceira alternativa](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quot) é usar `\Q` e `\E`. Basicamente, qualquer caractere entre o `\Q` e `\E` é interpretado literalmente, sem significado especial dentro da expressão:

```
String[] partes = s.split("\\Q.\\E");
```

Ambos produzem o mesmo resultado que `split("\\.")` (que por sinal, é a solução mais simples - as duas alternativas são úteis quando se tem strings muito grandes com vários caracteres especiais, pois aí é menos trabalhoso do que escapar um a um com `\`).

Comment: Complementando, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34619937) explica porque `split(".")` retorna um array vazio